# MPL 2.0. dynamically linking to GPL

Tags: licensing, gpl, mpl

Let say that library "A" is published under GPL.

Library "A" exposes some API functions for dynamic linking.

I wrote a wrapper library "B" for usage of "A" in another language.

Library "B" dynamically links to the library "A" (calls are made to the exposed API functions) .

I would like to publish my "B" wrapper library under MPL v.2.0.

The main question is... is this legal?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as "A" is published under GPL rather than LGPL, "B" is considered a derived work and must be distributed under GPL. GPL only stops at process boundary, only LGPL stops at dynamic link boundary.